# How to get a region of rotated Actor in libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

In a small game I am developing using libgdx, I have spears as game objects.
I implemented them using Scene2D, as a subclass of Actor. The spears can be rotated by multitudes of 90° . I want to have just the "speartip" part of my image as a part that "hurts" the Player, the shaft shall be harmless. So when I construct my Spear object, I also construct 2 rectangles that cover the tip and the shaft of the spear. But when my actor gets rotated using `setRotation()` , the rectangles obviously don't, cause they aren't "attached" to the spear object.

Do you have some suggestions on how to handle this kind of stuff? Code below.

```
    public TrapEntity(Texture texture, float pos_x, float pos_y, float width, float height, Vector2 center,
                  float rotation, Rectangle hurtZone, Rectangle specialZone) {
    super(texture, pos_x, pos_y, width, height, center, rotation);

    this.hurtZone = new Rectangle(hurtZone.getX(), hurtZone.getY(), hurtZone.getWidth(), hurtZone.getHeight());
    this.specialZone = new Rectangle(specialZone.getX(), specialZone.getY(), specialZone.getWidth(), specialZone.getHeight());

}
```

And the render method in the same class. I use it to render the bounds of the "hurtZone" rectangle:

```
    @Override
public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
    super.draw(batch, alpha);
    batch.end();
    sr.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
    sr.setTransformMatrix(batch.getTransformMatrix());
    sr.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    sr.setColor(Color.RED);
    sr.rect(hurtZone.getX(), hurtZone.getY(), hurtZone.getWidth(), hurtZone.getHeight());
    sr.end();
    batch.begin();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rectangles can't be rotated, I had to do a similar thing and struggled with finding a solution. The best solution I have found yet is to use a Polygon. You would do something like this;

```
    //Polygon for a rect is set by vertices in this order
    Polygon polygon = new Polygon(new float[]{0, 0, width, 0, width, height, 0, height});

    //properties to update each frame
    polygon.setPosition(item.getX(), item.getY());
    polygon.setOrigin(item.getOriginX(), item.getOriginY());
    polygon.setRotation(item.getRotation());
```

Then, to check if a point is within the rotated Polygon use;

```
    polygon.contains(x, y);
```

Comment: I've come across Polygons in my search too, but was wondering if there was an "easier" solution. Also, do you maybe have suggestions on how to check which part of my texture was, for example touched? No I have a rectangle for the bounds of the spear, as well as 2 rectangles for the shaft and tip. Before I implement that as Polygons, is there maybe a better way to check if the "tip" was touched, e.g. transforming touch coordinates to texture coordinates even though the texture was rotated?

Comment: You might just be able to do it with a few `Vector2`s. You might need to put pen to paper but you could probably have 1 `Vector2` that follows the origin of spear and another `Vector2` that follows roughly the tip of the spear, then experiment with some custom logic to get the result you want. For example (lets call them `originVec2` & `tipVec2`), if `tipVec2` is within your player, but `originVec2` is greater than a certain distance to the player, and/or the angle between `originVec2` & `tipVec2` is in a certain range, etc.. This kind of stuff just comes down to vigorous messing and tweaking.